# Android Studio - take picture and save it in a new activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already made an activity TakePicture that would capture an image and then store it in my phone gallery. My problem now is that I want to save each picture taken with the app in a new android activity called "Gallery" but I don't have any idea how.

Here's the code for taking the picture:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TakePicture extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    //keep track of camera capture intent
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    //captured picture uri
    private Uri picUri;
    final int PIC_CROP = 2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button240);

        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(TakePicture.this, YesTracker.class));
            }
        });


        Button btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button241);

        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(TakePicture.this, Home.class));
            }
        });

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_picture);
        //retrieve a reference to the UI button
        Button captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        //handle button clicks
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
            try {
                //use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                //display an error message
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            } //user is returning from cropping the image
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
                ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
                //display the returned cropped image
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }
    }
    private void performCrop(){
        try {
            //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            //indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            //set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            //indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            //retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_take_picture, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:id="@+id/button240"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HOME"
    android:id="@+id/button241"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button240"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/capture"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/picture"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_border" />
```

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: You can supply a path to which the photo will be stored. The developer site has a tutorial on the same. Take a look here - http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "save" anything in `Activity`, `Activity` is a screen that displays data and allows user to interact with your application - this is very rough definition though.
But you can store paths to photos in SQLite database or JSON file. Thus when you open "Gallery" activity - you can display photos by reading paths from storage and performing needed logic to that paths.